# CSS/HTML Slider. 1st Image should display on top of all then 2nd then 3rd... and so on

Tags: html, css, slider, z-index

No jQuery/Javascript simple html/css slider... see this

http://jsfiddle.net/Qrw76

HTML CODE

```
<div class="accordian">
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS Code goes here

```
* {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

.accordian {
width: 820px; height: 348px;
overflow: hidden;

/*Time for some styling*/
margin: 100px auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

/*A small hack to prevent flickering on some browsers*/
.accordian ul {
width: 2000px;
/*This will give ample space to the last item to move
instead of falling down/flickering during hovers.*/
}

.accordian li {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 120px;
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid #888;

box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

/*Transitions to give animation effect*/
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
/*If you hover on the images now you should be able to 
see the basic accordian*/
}

/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/
.accordian ul:hover li {width: 40px;

}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/
/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/
.accordian ul li:hover {width: 600px;
}

.accordian li img {
display: block;
}

/*Image title styles*/
.image_title {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position: absolute;
left: 0; bottom: 0; 
width: 640px;   
}
.image_title a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

In slider the first image (li) is behind 2nd one... and 2nd image is behind third.. and so on... last comes on top of all...

but what i want is 1st image should be top of all then after that 2nd .. then 3rd and 6th will be behind all .. simple...can someone do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index to each li using below jquery code.

JS

```
var s = $('.accordian ul li').size();
$('.accordian ul li').each(function(index){
    var z = s - index;
    $(this).css('z-index', z);
});
```

CSS :

```
.accordian li {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

**EDIT:** To remove the white space at the end

Add a last class to the last item in the accordion and remove box shadow for that item

CSS:

```
.accordian li.last{ box-shadow:none; }
```

Also remove the top shadow from the `.accordion`. If needed this can be added to the accordion item itself.

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/Qrw76/5/)

Comment: everything fine.. but WHITE is coming after last slide.. it looks white empty slide.. can you fix this plz